# restricting the number of switches that can be selected in android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, toggleswitch

We are developing an android application. In one of the pages, we have 15 toggle switches. When the user toggles the switch(to ON), the Boolean values will be stored in shared preferences. When the user revisits the page after login, the toggle switches will be shown as per his previous selection. Now we would like to restrict the number of switches that can be toggled to ON to 9. Your help is most appreciable in this regard.

Here I am putting the sample code

```
     import android.widget.CompoundButton;
     import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;


     public class favorites extends ActionBarActivity implements        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

int c = 0;
String accdet;
String SessionID;
String favacctno,DATOFBIRTH;
 Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Logout lg;
    String LastLogin;
String uname3;
String Custid;
String acountno;
String acctdet;
Switch tg,tg1,tg2,tg3,tg4,tg5,tg6,tg7,tg8,tg9,tga,tgb,tgc,tgd,tge,tgch;
 private TextView switchStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites);
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


   tg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tga.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tgb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tgc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tgd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tge.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);      

    tgch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);          

    countDownTimer=      new CountDownTimer(5*60000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TextView tv10 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    // tv10.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {

          SessionID="L";
           Editor edit = sp.edit();
           edit.putString("SessionID", SessionID);
           edit.commit();
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Auth.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
          //  intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            intent.putExtra("Exp", "Expired");
            startActivity(intent);
         countDownTimer.cancel();

         //showAlertDialog(AcctDetails.this, "Error","Session Expired.Kindly login once again.", false);
     //  finish() ;// finish ActivityB
     }
  }.start();   

    try{        


        String uname = sp.getString("UserName", "User");
        SessionID=sp.getString("SessionID","SessionID");
        favacctno=sp.getString("favacctno", "favacctno");
        DATOFBIRTH=sp.getString("DATOFBIRTH", "DATOFBIRTH");
        LastLogin = sp.getString("LastLogin", "LastLogin");
        String usname = "Welcome " + uname;
        TextView DispUName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        DispUName.setText(usname); 
        final String uname3=uname +"||"+SessionID+"||"+"No"+"||"+favacctno+"||"+DATOFBIRTH+"||"+LastLogin;              

          Custid = getIntent().getStringExtra("Custid");

      }

     catch

          {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception Occured.Kindly try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println( e);
          }
     }


       final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if (isChecked)
        {
            c++;
        }else
        {
            c--;
        }
        if (c<=9)
        {
            if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.accdet_Switch1)
            {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("chqbkreq", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.acctsumm_Switch)
            {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("accsumm", true);
                editor.commit();         

            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.accstmt_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("accstmt", true);
                editor.commit();
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.CRL_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("CRL", true);
                editor.commit(); 
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.CSE_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("CSE", true);
                editor.commit();

            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.inwchq_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("inwchq", true);
                editor.commit();  
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.Unclramt_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("unclramt", true);
                editor.commit();


            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depdet_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("depdet", true);
                editor.commit();  
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depsumm_Switch)
            {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("depsumm", true);
                editor.commit();

            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depstmt_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("depstmt", true);
                editor.commit();   
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loandet_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("loandet", true);
                editor.commit();

            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loansumm_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("loansumm", true);
                editor.commit();  
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loanstmt_Switch)
            {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("loanstmt", true);
                editor.commit();

            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.AM_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("AM", true);
                editor.commit();        
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.forex_Switch)
            {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
                editor.putBoolean("forex", true);
                editor.commit();
            }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.chqbreq_Switch)
            {


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("chqbkreq", true);
                editor.commit(); 
             }

            Toast.makeText(favorites.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            c--;
            buttonView.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(favorites.this, "Only 9 Options can be selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
       }
```

App getting crash

```
05-12 16:23:42.362: W/dalvikvm(706): threadid=1: thread exiting with     uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kvbank.kvb_ebook/kvbank.kvb_epassbook.favorites}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at kvbank.kvb_epassbook.favorites.onCreate(favorites.java:111)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-12 16:23:42.392: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
and 11 more........................
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want. What happens when a tenth `Switch` is clicked? Should one of the others be switched off? Should the tenth immediately switch back to off? Should it not switch at all?

Comment: You could add a switchedOnCount method that returns the number of switches that are on and then use this in the `onCheckedChangedListener`s along the lines of `if(isChecked & (switchedOnCount() < 9))` ...  Of course `switchedOnCount` could alternately return true or false.

Comment: Sorry for that Mike. When the tenth switch is ON, message has to come that only nine switches can be selected, and the tenth switch should switch back to off. Could I have a sample code on using switchedOnCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener in your activity, and add this code :

```
tg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
tg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
...
tge.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Now inside your onCheckedChanged():

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked)
    {
        count++;
    }else
    {
        count--;
    }
    if (count<=9)
    {
        if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.accdet_Switch1)
        {
            //Do respective operation
        }
        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.acctsumm_Switch)
        {
            //Do respective operation
        }
        ...
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    {
        count--;
        buttonView.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only 9 Options can be selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**count** is a global integer variable.

Comment: When I am switching one OFF and switching another one ON. still same message "Only 9 options can be selected"

Comment: But i don't have that problem. Its working fine for me. Make the count a global variable.

Comment: I am also getting a null point exception. I have updated the code. Could you please check and let me know what might be the exact issue

Comment: post your stacktrace as well. Exactly where are you getting NPE...? The code i posted is working fine for me

Comment: The error is inside your onCreate(). You haven't initialized your switches. You have set the listener on null variables. That is the reason for your error. Just add tg=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.youCheckBox); before you are setting the listener on your CheckBoxes(You have to do this for every CheckBox).

Comment: thank you very much. I have pointed it out. But very much helpful. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated answer. I have initialised the switches and rechecked. Issue solved
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
        import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

```
  public class favorites extends ActionBarActivity implements        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

int c = 0;
String accdet;
String SessionID;
String favacctno,DATOFBIRTH;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
 ConnectionDetector cd;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
 Logout lg;
  String LastLogin;
String uname3;
String Custid;
String acountno;
String acctdet;
Switch tg,tg1,tg2,tg3,tg4,tg5,tg6,tg7,tg8,tg9,tga,tgb,tgc,tgd,tge,tgch;
 private TextView switchStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.favorites);
  final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
          .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

     tg = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.accdet_Switch1); 
 tg1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.acctsumm_Switch);    
  tg2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.accstmt_Switch);        
  tg3 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.CRL_Switch);
  tg4 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.CSE_Switch);
      tg5 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.inwchq_Switch);        
      tg6 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.Unclramt_Switch);        
      tg7 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.depdet_Switch);
    tg8 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.depsumm_Switch);
 tg9 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.depstmt_Switch);        
  tga = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.loandet_Switch);        
      tgb = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.loansumm_Switch);
    tgc = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.loanstmt_Switch);
    tgd = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.AM_Switch);        
     tge = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.forex_Switch); 
     tgch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.chqbreq_Switch); 

 tg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tg4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tg6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tg7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tg8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tg9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    tga.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tgb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tgc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tgd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 tge.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);      

    tgch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);          

    countDownTimer=      new CountDownTimer(5*60000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {

      SessionID="L";
       Editor edit = sp.edit();
       edit.putString("SessionID", SessionID);
       edit.commit();
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Auth.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      //  intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        intent.putExtra("Exp", "Expired");
        startActivity(intent);
     countDownTimer.cancel();

     //showAlertDialog(AcctDetails.this, "Error","Session Expired.Kindly login once again.", false);
 //  finish() ;// finish ActivityB
 }
 }.start();   

try{        


    String uname = sp.getString("UserName", "User");
    SessionID=sp.getString("SessionID","SessionID");
    favacctno=sp.getString("favacctno", "favacctno");
    DATOFBIRTH=sp.getString("DATOFBIRTH", "DATOFBIRTH");
    LastLogin = sp.getString("LastLogin", "LastLogin");
    String usname = "Welcome " + uname;
    TextView DispUName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    DispUName.setText(usname); 
    final String uname3=uname +"||"+SessionID+"||"+"No"+"||"+favacctno+"||"+DATOFBIRTH+"||"+LastLogin;              

      Custid = getIntent().getStringExtra("Custid");

  }

 catch

      {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception Occured.Kindly try again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
System.out.println( e);
      }
 }


   final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (isChecked)
      {
            c++;
        }else
     {
          c--;
     }
     if (c<=9)
        {
         if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.accdet_Switch1)
         {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
               editor.putBoolean("chqbkreq", true);
              editor.commit();
          }
            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.acctsumm_Switch)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("accsumm", true);
             editor.commit();         

          }

            else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.accstmt_Switch)
         {
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("accstmt", true);
             editor.commit();
           }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.CRL_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("CRL", true);
            editor.commit(); 
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.CSE_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("CSE", true);
            editor.commit();

        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.inwchq_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("inwchq", true);
            editor.commit();  
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.Unclramt_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("unclramt", true);
            editor.commit();


        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depdet_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("depdet", true);
            editor.commit();  
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depsumm_Switch)
        {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("depsumm", true);
            editor.commit();

        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.depstmt_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("depstmt", true);
            editor.commit();   
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loandet_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("loandet", true);
            editor.commit();

        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loansumm_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("loansumm", true);
            editor.commit();  
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.loanstmt_Switch)
        {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("loanstmt", true);
            editor.commit();

        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.AM_Switch)
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("AM", true);
            editor.commit();        
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.forex_Switch)
        {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();                            
            editor.putBoolean("forex", true);
            editor.commit();
        }

        else if (buttonView.getId()==R.id.chqbreq_Switch)
        {


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("chqbkreq", true);
            editor.commit(); 
         }

        Toast.makeText(favorites.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    {
        c--;
        buttonView.setChecked(false);
        Toast.makeText(favorites.this, "Only 9 Options can be selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

}
       }